# Retrieve values from response xml using XML Slurper didin't work

Tags: groovy, soapui, xmlslurper

I am trying to retrieve a value from a XML response but it prints nothing.Please note that I am using SOAP UI to test the webservice and has written a simple piece of code to retrieve the policyid from the below response xml.

Below is the code; if you see the second line of screenshots of the, it prints EMPTY value.

[image: SOAP UI Logs/Output]

I tried different options suggested in various websites but nothing helped

**Groovy Script**

```
def response = context.expand( '${XMLService#Response}' )

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response);

log.info xml

log.info(xml.EQuoteResponse.Policy.PolicyId.text())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you parse the xml, you're effectively at the root node in the result...  So you don't need the `EQuoteResponse` when querying the document

```
log.info(xml.Policy.PolicyId.text())
```

Will work

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
def tstStep =  testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["yourTestCaseName"].testSteps["YourXMLRequestName"]
def response = tstStep.getPropertyValue("response")
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
log.info "PolicyId:::" + xml.Policy.PolicyId.text()
```